Intelephense not indenting one file, but indenting all others
I have one file in my current project that are being formatted differently than all the other ones. It seems that this file is getting indentation of 2 spaces, while every other file is getting 4 spaces. This file is in the same directory as other files that have the correct indentation (4 spaces). There are a ton of settings around indentation in Intelephense and I have no idea why this file wouldn't be handled the same as other ones. Has anyone run into this?


What does it say in VScodes statusbar (right side)? Spaces: 2? You can change it by clicking it

ahh that worked! I didn't know you could do that. thanks!
